# Insert groupby result into new column ONCE per instance

Tags: python, pandas, merge, transformation

DataFrame as so:

```
new
Color  Value
0   Red    100
1   Red    150
2  Blue     50
```

I'm inserting the counts of duplicates into a new Series with:

`new['Repeats'] = new.groupby(['Color'])[new.columns[-1]].transform('count')`

Which results in:

```
Color  Value  Repeats
0   Red    100        2
1   Red    150        2
2  Blue     50        1
```

Is there a way to get the same result, but only have the 'Repeats' entered once per instance like so:

```
Color  Value  Repeats
0   Red    100        2
1   Red    150        
2  Blue     50        1
```

It seems silly to me, but a client requested as such.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After performing the `transform`, use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) to make the duplicates empty strings:

```
new.loc[new['Color'].duplicated(), 'Repeats'] = ''
```

The resulting output:

```
  Color  Value Repeats
0   Red    100       2
1   Red    150        
2  Blue     50       1
```

Note that you could also assign the duplicates as `np.nan`, but you'd need to convert the `'Repeats'` columns to string dtype first, otherwise the counts would become floats.

Comment: Beat me to it... :) I would replace with `np.nan` to keep the Repeats column numeric instead of introducing a new type with the empty string.

Comment: This is beautiful.  Thank you!

Comment: @3novak: Yeah, my initial instinct is to use `np.nan`, but doing so would convert the column from `int` to `float` dtype, making the counts go from `2` to `2.0`, etc.  If @bmeredith's client is picky enough not to like repeated counts, they'd probably not like floats as well.  The way around that would be to convert the column to string dtype first, or something like that, so you'd need to change the type regardless.

Comment: Yeaah. They are reading the data in as str anyways, so the conversion wouldn't matter a whole bunch, but they are very picky.  The provided solution works well enough and is quick.

The data is generally <= 100k rows, so this will suffice.

Comment: Aha, I see. Good call.